# How would I make each individual line in a JSON file a string using RegEx in VSCode?

Tags: regex

I want to surround a list of phone numbers in a text file with quotation marks on each line

I tried using \n but to add a quotation mark to the end but it made the strings move to the same line

For example, the RegEx would surround the start and end of each individual number below and add brackets before and after them

```
07793440319 --> "07793440319"
01207934668 --> "01207934668"
01513679015 --> "01513679015"
07844202852 --> "07844202852"
01933837980 --> "01933837980"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `^\d+$` or - if there are always 11 digits on a line -  `^\d{11}$` and replace with `"$&"`.

The `^\d+$` matches a start of a line, then 1+ digits, then an end of line position, and the `$&` backreference to the whole match inserts the match back during the replacement.

The `\d{11}` pattern matches eleven digits.

[image]

Comment: What is the need for the + sign in the Find Field? Thanks.

Comment: @wellows one or more of the preceding token

Comment: @wellows `+` is a quantifier that means *match preceding token 1 or more times*.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it, with your values, using capturing groups.
CMD + F, use find and replace, select regex option and fill in the boxes accordingly:

[image]